# Image click function is not working during resize and tab view

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp

I have created header icons like home and user. In desktop view, if i click the user image it displays the respective redirect page. If i minimize it in tab or mobile view
,it displays nothing. this issue happens only for user image but not for home image. Below the code i tried.

```
<div id="header">
            <a id="home" onclick="homeclick();"
             style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="images/home.png"
                height='28' width='25' /> </a>


         <a id="user" title="User" style="cursor: pointer;" class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-8"><img
            src="images/user.png" height='25' width='25' /> </a> 



    </div>  

 <div class="md-modal md-effect-5" id="modal-8">
        <div class="md-content">
            <h2>Welcome <%=session.getAttribute("displayName")%></h2>
            <div>
                <p style="display: inline-block; width: 25%;">Last Login </p><p style="display: inline-block;width: 75%">: <%=session.getAttribute("lastLogin")%></p>
                <p style="display: inline-block; width: 25%;">Display Name </p><p style="display: inline-block;width: 75%">: <%=session.getAttribute("displayName")%></p>
                <p style="display: inline-block; width: 25%;">Email ID </p><p style="display: inline-block;width: 75%">: <span id="mail"><%=session.getAttribute("mail")%></span></p>
                <div class="allButtons">


                <button class="md-close">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="menuIcons">&#9776;</div>
    <div id="headerListIcons" style="display : none ; ">        
        </div>

        var hrz ='<ul class="header-viwmenu">';
            hrz += '<li id="home" onclick="homeclick();"'
                +'title="Home"  style="cursor: pointer"><img src="images/home.png"'
                +'height="25" width="25" /> </li>'          

            +'<li id="user" title="User" style="cursor: pointer;" class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-8">'
            +'<img src="images/user.png" height="25" width="25"> </li>'
            </ul>'; 
            $('#headerListIcons').append(hrz);
```

Answer (score 0):

By placing script before an end of body tag, resolves the problem. It is important to set display attribute as block !important.